Apache .htaccess rule to serve 404 of non-existent images
Images physical path:
/img/a/b/c/abc-img.jpg

/img/a/c/b/acb-img.jpg

/img/b/c/a/bca-img.jpg

/img/c/b/a/cba-img.jpg - not exits

mod_rewrite rewrite this to like /img/abc-img.jpg and all works ok
"GET /img/a/b/c/abc-img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200
This rule to allow images only:
/img/.htaccess:
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
    <Files ~ "(?i)^.*\.(jpg|gif|png)$">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</IfModule>

If image not exists client got 403
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /img/c/b/a
"GET /img/c/b/a/cba-img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 403
How to make him return 404 instead 403 ?
I don't know if this is possible.

The reason for the 403 is obvious: your granting rule inside the mod_authz conditional does not get applied if the request does not target an existing file inside the physical file system. I wonder why you need this construction at all ... Do you really have other files inside the /img/ folder that you need to deny access to, so that you then have to grant access to those image files again as an exception? Can't you simply grant access to all files inside that folder?
